# helper for all views in a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view-helpers

Is there a way to create a view helper file that will be available to all views in a namespace? Like application_helper.rb, but only working for a given namespace.

Specifically, I have a namespace called "office". I want to set up a view helper that is accessible to any view within the "office" namespace.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you have a BaseController for that specific namespace. For example,

```
class Office::BaseController < ApplicationController
  helper :office   
end
```

And inherit this controller in all the other controllers within that namespace.

```
class Office::UsersController < Office::BaseController
  def index
      ..
  end
end
```

Now all the methods within the helper office_helper.rb is present within this namespace.

Also, this is a **good practice** to separate the concerns / code for the controller namespaces.